# Warning: your content is blank

Tags: wordpress, wpallimport

When I am importing **`csv`** file in WordPress

> Warning: your content is blank

error is showing and the file is not importing.

Comment: Please give more detail. Is the csv a database migration?

Comment: Yes! and my file is getting terminated whenever I want to  import the file.

Comment: Check your delimiter settings. WordPress provides a very handy guide on exporting and importing databases. https://codex.wordpress.org/Restoring_Your_Database_From_Backup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To insert the data in post you required a content without content you can not create the post this is the wordpress default behaviour.

You can do one thing put   in your content field column. it will display blanks space and wordpress consider it as a content.

So,By this way it will resolve your issue.

Comment: I have content in my excel file

Comment: what is the content can you paste one sentence over here. Doe it having special characters?

Comment: id | Title     | Departure Countries |Departure Cities  | Destination 
320 | Dubai Mickeys Music Festival | Dubai |  Italy                                       this is the custom post type content

Comment: What is the code share your code in your question now. It seems like you did any mistake in code.